# when I close my laptop lid and reopen my machine suspends

Tags: laptop, power-management, suspend

I have this weird problem with my new Xubuntu 14.04 installation. When I close my laptop lid, the box will suspend alright. After I decide to reopen my box to continue what am doing the screen will flicker and ask me to login. After I supply the password, the screen will go dark and the HD led will appear busy for a while and thats it. I always reboot my box.

I hope I have been clear on the nature of the problem.

Comment: Look at this [BUG: Black screen after login from suspend in Xubuntu 14.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1303736) and try the suggestion from answer [#56](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1303736/comments/56).

Comment: Try to suspend by Menu>Close Session>Suspend then close the lid.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing (or re-installing) Xorg multitouch and synaptics.  I am using an Asus q500a and that solved 99% of my lid open/close issues.

These are the steps I used, and I have no idea why it helps with lid actions but it solved it for me.

1. Open terminal and execute following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-input-multitouch
   ```

   be sure you don't remove any other package than xserver-xorg-input-multitouch

   ```
   sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
   ```

   again follow the same precaution.
2. Once removed execute these commands to install it again:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-multitouch
   sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
   ```

   again be sure you don't remove any other packages while installing it.
3. Once installed execute following commands to reconfigure it:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep "^xserver" | tr '\n' ' ')
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

Comment: I appears to have worked,.. Thanks man... but am down grading to Kubuntu 13.10